# Play! Framework 2 REST Authentication and Authorization for Android Client

Tags: android, rest, authentication, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm currently working on an application that has web version (Play! Framework 2.2.x) and Android Client. Due to the fact that Play! is fully RESTful I want to communicate between Play! and Android with JSON requests and responses. Web version of the application is using Play Authenticate plugin which supports authentication and authorization. I would like to know how to enable login in Android Client that would use Play! app and how to secure the communication between Play! app and Android Client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After not getting a reply for my question I figured out the following solution. Each user has it's own name and password and a token. This token is being set during registration and gets updated every two days. I save username and token inside shared preferences in android application and authenticate each request from client with those two fields. Since it was a student project I thought it might be a good choice, but the production product should have better security.