# Rest Apis authentication on Play framework for mobile application

Tags: android, rest, oauth-2.0, playframework-2.6, api-authorization

I am an android developer and I am trying to learn server side. I have created a server side application with play 2 that gives RESTful apis. I have an android application as the client. I know how handle sessions in android by saving the access tokens in SharedPreferences. I want to know how to create this access token at the server side when user logs in and properly handle them at the serverside with time out and other things. I did some googling and I found Oauth 1 and 2. But from what I understand, they are used for authorizing 3rd party logins (like fb or google logins). Please point me in the right direction

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23328266/play-framework-2-rest-authentication-and-authorization-for-android-client) question in Stackoverflow but it doesn't seems to be the correct approach

Please bear with me and forgive any mistakes I am completely new to the Backend world.